# Making a table span across several pages on pdf from R Markdown (when longtable not available)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex, xtable

I have a table that potentially can be very long and I would like it to print over a few pages if need be, however, from my reading, this requires the `longtable` package to set the `tabular.environment = "longtable"` in `print.xtable(...)`.  The `longtable` package is not available for my version of R (3.6.1).  Is there a workaround?

This is my current code:

```
ortho <- xtable(orthoInstructions)
bold <- function(x) {paste('{\\textbf{',x,'}}', sep ='')}

align(ortho) <- c("p{0.1cm}","p{6cm}","p{15cm}")

print.xtable(ortho, 
             include.rownames = FALSE, 
             hline.after = NULL,
             sanitize.colnames.function = bold)
```

Comment: `longtable` is a LaTeX package, not a R package. I suggest you to use the `kableExtra` (R) package for your long table.

Comment: Hi, I followed your suggestion but have come across a separate problem, please can you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040243/error-in-kable-and-kableextra-in-r-markdown if you have time?